# Error de dependencias en Java con SpringBoot (bean)

Tags: java, netbeans, spring-boot, java-8, spring-security

estoy intentado crear una aplicación para aprender, pero al ejecutarla me encuentro con el siguiente error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'rolService'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rolService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'rolRepository'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rolRepository' defined in com.porfolioDanielLlanes.demo.Security.Repository.RolRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException:
Could not create query for public abstract java.util.Optional com.porfolioDanielLlanes.demo.Security.Repository.RolRepository.finByRolNombre(com.porfolioDanielLlanes.demo.Security.Enums.RolNombre); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.porfolioDanielLlanes.demo.Security.Repository.RolRepository.finByRolNombre(com.porfolioDanielLlanes.demo.Security.Enums.RolNombre)! No property 'finByRolNombre' found for type 'Rol'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.porfolioDanielLlanes.demo.Security.Repository.RolRepository.finByRolNombre(com.porfolioDanielLlanes.demo.Security.Enums.RolNombre)! No property 'finByRolNombre' found for type 'Rol'
```

La clase principal

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

la clase rolService

```
package com.porfolioDanielLlanes.demo.Security.Service;

import com.porfolioDanielLlanes.demo.Security.Entity.Rol;
import com.porfolioDanielLlanes.demo.Security.Enums.RolNombre;
import com.porfolioDanielLlanes.demo.Security.Repository.RolRepository;
import java.util.Optional;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Transactional
public class RolService {
    @Autowired
    RolRepository rolRepository;
    
    public Optional<Rol> getByRolNombre(RolNombre rolNombre){
        return rolRepository.finByRolNombre(rolNombre);
    }
    
    public void  save(Rol rol){
        rolRepository.save(rol);
    }
}
```

La clase RolRepository

```
package com.porfolioDanielLlanes.demo.Security.Repository;

import com.porfolioDanielLlanes.demo.Security.Entity.Rol;
import com.porfolioDanielLlanes.demo.Security.Enums.RolNombre;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface RolRepository extends JpaRepository<Rol, Integer>{
    Optional<Rol> finByRolNombre(RolNombre rolNombre);
}
```

El proyecto importa mas clases en el controlador, pero creo que el problema radica en alguna dependecia de la clase RolService o RolRepository que hace que los métodos no puedan ser ejecutados

Comment: El problema es que JPA no sabe cómo crear tu RolRepository ya que no hay una clase que implemente el método findByRolNombre ni le defines una Query

Comment: Muchas gracias, no me había fijado en ese error de tipeo, pensé que era un problema de dependencias.

Comment: Si solucionaste tu problema pública una respuesta con la solución a la que llegaste, así servirá a futuros lectores.